# Someone hacked my pc, please help. (debug.log.sent)

Tags: virus, user-accounts, debug

Once every hour my computer sends out debug.log files. Example:

```
debug.log.110422_171810.sent 4/22/2011 10:13am
```

I don't know to whom these files are being sent, nor do I know what's in them. I do know that recently I had fraudulent charges on several of the credit cards that I have used on my computer. Only on my computer. The very next day after I used them.

1. How can I stop it?
2. Can I trace where the files are being sent to?
3. How can I prove any of this or pursue this legally?

Comment: How does your computer send out the files?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with installing DropBox which handles large files. I've noticed that my debug.log files were created and sent a day after I installed it. Although I too have had fraudulent charges on my credit cards recently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Answer (score 7):

Format your drive and clean reinstall your operating system, then file a fraud alert with your credit report and with your banks. Change your password on everything. EVERYTHING.

If a computer is compromised, that's the only 99.9% sure way to fix it(*). As far as traceability and legal recourse, you're up a creek. Unless you have some major money or corporate/government backing to investigate with, don't even bother because you'll probably get nowhere.

(*) barring nasty stuff that's mostly theoretical like hardware-level rootkits

Comment: If @ALEX really cares about the forensic aspects of his question, he should capture an offline image of his hard drive before reformatting it... or simply remove the drive and replace it with a new one.

Comment: @Miles Correct, however it would be a purely academic pursuit. It won't do much about #2 (tracing) if his goal is #3 (pressing charges).

Comment: True, but on the other hand it would be something he could turn over to the cops when he files the police report (which the credit card companies all but require). Maybe it'd be useful to them, maybe not, but it can't hurt to try (unless you drop it on your little toe...).

Comment: +1 for suggesting that it be nuked from orbit. its the only way to be sure

Answer (score 1):

The exact same files are made on my Mac. They reside in the Applications/Akamai/Logs folder.

The Akamai Readme file says:

> The Akamai NetSession Interface runs
>   as a service to manage downloads and
>   to let you manage the download
>   process. It was installed on your
>   computer when you downloaded content
>   that uses the service to provide
>   secure, high integrity downloads of
>   large files.

I don’t know if it is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect your computer from the network. NOW. (well, you might want to finish reading this first). If you have access to another computer, download the free version of [AVG Anti-Virus](http://www.avg.com/us-en/buyav-ppc_1) and use it to scan for rootkits. If you have one, then reimage your hard drive. If you have data that you absolutely cannot afford to lose, then scan that before backing it up. You don't want something you backed up reinfecting your computer.

Comment: i'd suggest Windows security essentials over AVG. I'm rather for the nuking from orbit option tho.

Comment: yeah this is slightly more risky, but I would do this first if there is important data that you can't lose